# Is there package manager console in Rider?

Tags: entity-framework, console, nuget-package, rider

I would like to know updated information about aviability package manager console in Rider. I didn't find any information about this on the Internet but I hope there is a way to enable it. Someone can help with it or I have to install VS?
Or how I can use commandlets like "Add-Migration" or "Scaffold-DbContext"? They aren't work. I installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Add-Migration` or `Scaffold-DbContext` commands are PowerShell-based, and the Package Manager Console ties to several Visual Studio-specific objects making it impossible to host it elsewhere - in this case Rider.

In Rider you can run these in terminal and they should be equivalent to the ones you mentioned for VS:

- `dotnet ef migrations add MigrationName`
- `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`

More details are available on JetBrains blog: [Running EF commands in Rider](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/09/running-entity-framework-core-commands-rider/)